# How to format date as 'DD-MM-YYYY' from bigint value in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm desperately trying to figure out how to display a bigint column value which represents a timestamp into a date like 'DD-MM-YYYY'.

I tried multiple combinations, they all fail, but the only one that does not fail but does not give me exactly what I need is this :

```
select to_timestamp(last_downloaded/1000) from stats;
```

This one displays a date like `2021-08-30 15:34:08+02` but I need it to display `30-08-2021`

the column '**last_downloaded**' is a **bigint** type.

How to manage this ?

Comment: Wrap the result in a `to_char()` call.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `to_char` with the output of `to_timestamp` and the mask `DD-MM-YYYY`, e.g.

```
SELECT to_char(to_timestamp(last_downloaded/1000),'DD-MM-YYYY') 
FROM stats;
```